# How to increase iOS map location update rate to 10 times per second?

Tags: ios, location

I'm doing a pedometer application and use CLLocationManager to update user's location. but the delegate's method "- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations" update rate about 1 time per second. I want to know if some code can increase update rate greater than 1 time per second. I would be very grateful.

Comment: Given that the best accuracy you can get from location services is about 10m, increasing the update rate isn't going to help you much unless the user is moving more than 20m/s - 72km/h is pretty fast walking

Comment: Yes, you're right. but I intend to location the racing car, to calculate the racing car every lap time, so this need the higher frequency of locationing to ensure the best accuracy of time when racing car is about to reach the finish line.

Comment: You can't change the rate of location updates, but your GPS positional accuracy will still be the limiting factor.  You can only know where the car is +/- 10m - that is about 2 car lengths